# Garbage collection: Initial marking and concurrent marking

Tags: java, garbage-collection

For the Concurrent-Mark-Sweep garbage collector in Java; I'm not clear what is different between these two phases. Why is the concurrent marking needed ? Did initial marking not find all live objects ?

Comment: It's a way to try and minimise the amount of time that the GC has to stop the application.

Comment: So are only some objects scared and subsequently marked in the initial marking phase and the rest are scanned and marked during the concurrent phase?

Comment: You're thinking of things too simplistically. The GC doesn't just do the same thing 3 times for fun.

Comment: What do you mean by "initial marking"?

Comment: @meriton, it's the first phase of the CMS garbage collector

Comment: @BoristheSpider, I figure it has a reason to do things 3 times (initial mark, concurrent mark, remark) but I don't fully understand why, hence the post. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

CMS is used, so called 3-color marking algorithm for marking live objects.

- white - unmarked
- gray - object is marked, but its outbound references not processed
- black - object is marked and all outbound references are processed

Marking starts with graying out objects reachable from **roots**, and it is considered finished when no more gray objects are available.

Concurrent marking in CMS does marking in **old space only**. So all references outside of old space are **root references**.

They are

- local variables available is thread stacks
- references from young space to old

As only old space is suitable for concurrent marking, all stacks and young space should be precessed in stop-the-world fashion. This constitutes `initial-mark` phase of CMS.

Once `initial-mark` is finish CMS have number of grayed objects in old space to start concurrent marking. During concurrent marking black objects may revert back to gray if they are modified by application threads. Card marking writer barrier allow CMS to track modification.

Finally CMS is doing another stop-the-world pause `remark`. Remark rescans stack and young space again and finished marking of old space (most reachable objects are already black so marking is fairly quick). Young space and stacks are not tracked by write barrier, so CMS have to rescan them to find new references to old space.

After `remark` is finished there are only black and white objects in old space, thus sweeping can proceed.

You can read more details about CMS collector in [this article](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/06/understanding-gc-pauses-in-jvm-hotspots_02.html).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply.  Your article says "Card table (see card marking write barrier) is used to identify modified portions of memory in old space, but thread stacks and young space should be scanned once again." I thought items on tread stacks are the roots.

So from this, it sounds like during re-mark we take another look at objects that were modified during the concurrent mark to see if they are still live and we then again scan the thread stacks forming a new tree. Is that a correct understanding ?

Comment: We do not care if objects are "still alive". Goal is to find object which are unreachable. If some objects have become unreachable during concurrent phase they will remain undetected until next CMS cycle. That effect is called "floating garbage"